# Is there any way to change the size of icons (vim-devicons) without changing the font-size?

Tags: plugins, terminal, icons, neovim

I've installed [**NERDTree**](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) and [**vim-devicons**](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons) plugins for customizing my workspace and I find that size of icons is too small, so I wanted to make them bigger without changing font-size (current font-size comfortable for me).

I've tried to find solution on original documentation, read forums etc. Also I tried to find some special Nerd Font that will have bigger icons size but unfortunately everything was unsuccessful.

Link below is an example that shows current size of my icons and font.

[example with NERDTree window, tabs and status line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLOtq.png)

I'm using Windows PowerShell as my terminal and neovim as my editor.

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how to solve my problem or tell another way (or may be another plugins) to add icons and files tree to vim.

Comment: i am looking for the same. did you find a work around? then please post a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Those icons are just text and you can only have one font and font size for the whole terminal emulator's window. Therefore, you can't adjust their size separately from the rest of the text.